# IMPORTXML formula returns #N/A

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape token balance from one web site:

https://mainnet.aion.network/#/account/0xa02b21a21088ce2349914c92632e5ec3cdf8487c58ce210e44770da3e339eaed

Using formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://mainnet.aion.network/#/account/0xa02b21a21088ce2349914c92632e5ec3cdf8487c58ce210e44770da3e339eaed","//span[@class='strong']")
```

It is returning

> #N/A message, "imported content is empty"

Am I missing some parameter maybe?